# How does one overcome the trials and tribulations of Webkit zoom-related issues?

Tags: css, webkit, zooming, presentation

Webkit is an awful renderer in my opinion.  As a web designer/developer, I take into account how my design looks at every magnification.  Webkit handles this extremely poorly.  Margins, padding, and borders all get rendered extremely poorly across various magnifications and there is no CSS you can use that is "cross-zoom" compliant in WebKit.  Zoom in and out of any webpage in IE, Firefox, Opera and it is consistent.  Take a look at this site, for instance:

http://development.mminc.co/davidphotos/

Try using the carousel at the bottom at different magnifications in IE or Firefox.  Works fine, right?  Now try the same thing in Chrome or Safari.  BOOM!  A developer's nightmare!  Please, if anyone knows of any tricks of the trade to get Webkit to behave with something that even Trident is able to successfully do I'd like to hear it.  I've heard of a jQuery zoom plugin, but that is sort of a last resort.  I've looked everywhere for the issue but no one even mentions Webkit zoom issues.  It's like it's taboo or something. Personally I think it's one of the biggest blunders of the modern browser era, especially when such a (otherwise) great browser like Chrome is giving me more trouble with presentation issues than IE7.

EDIT:  I feel I should be more general and use an example where it is obvious only HTML and CSS are implemented.

http://www.gamespot.com/

Webkit forces a line-break with the top menu w/ zoom tests, but other browsers don't.  It is a major issue with the engine and if there are any concrete solutions I'd like to hear them.  If there isn't then I think this issue should be addressed and resolved immediately; it is an eyesore to users and a nightmare for developers. The fact that it isn't addressed anywhere on the net is troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't answering how to fix WebKit zoom issues in general, but it should help with your specific problem.

You're using [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/).

Even the [simple demo](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html) shows the same problems you describe.

So, that plugin is simply broken when it comes to zooming with WebKit browsers.

You could either ask the author of the plugin for advice, or find a different carousel plugin.

For instance, this one doesn't seem to have any problems when you zoom in using a WebKit browser:

http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm *(look at the "dispItems" demo)*

Comment: It has nothing to do with jCarousel in my opinion.  Go to http://www.gamespot.com/ and look at the top menu and you'll notice Webkit forces a line break on zoom where Gecko doesn't.

Comment: While I agree with you JCarousel might not be the best option as it is 5 years old, I am very worried that there is no discussion of WebKit zoom issues in general for regular HTML/CSS stylings.  It is a major flaw in the engine.

Comment: Obviously it is WebKit's fault, but trying to work around the specific bug in question (I don't know what the exact bug is) is a valid choice here. Otherwise, try following the steps here: http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html - particularly searching for an existing bug. It's also worth checking here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list